# Reshaping ear climber back to fit larger ears

Tags: jewelry, wire

I have this pair of ear climbers - https://www.etsy.com/listing/257143616/tiny-dagger-stud-earrings-dagger-stud

The piece here is slightly too short for my ears (the angled part just barely doesn't come out of the piercing).
[image: back of ear climber linked in post]

Is it feasible to straighten and re-shape a little larger angle there without breaking the wire off?  If so, any tips would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just rebending the wire is likely to break it.  Theoretically, it could be unsoldered and the earrings remade.

From your link, it looks like they retail for $24.  You would spend more than that for a jeweler to do the work.  The question suggests that you aren't an experienced jewelry maker, yourself, so this wouldn't be something you likely could tackle and expect an attractive result.

The company that makes it looks like a small operation that makes these themselves, and they do custom orders.  I would contact them and see if they would make you a pair in the right size.  Your existing pair you could give to a friend or resell.

Comment: It looks like the back acts a little like a spring clip.  If it was plain wire, it would bend a little every time you put them in or take them out until they become loose.  To prevent this, the back is often made of a stiffer alloy or treated to make it stiffer, and the metal is brittle.  Where soft wire will give you an indication that it is weakening, a brittle piece will just suddenly snap.  I don't recommend bending it, but if you do want to try, even if it is plain wire, don't modify an existing bend and don't try to make a sharp bend.  (cont'd)

Comment: Instead, lock the existing bend in round nose pliers, as Elmy suggests.  Use a second pair of pliers to secure the solder joint that holds the two pieces together.  Put a small, gradual bend along the entire short side to open up the back a little.  Repeat the process on the long side, putting another small, gradual bend along the long arm to move the end back into position.  You won't be able to gain much width, though.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to contact the manufacturer, as fixer 1234 already wrote, especially if this is a reoccuring problem they aren't aware of.

If they refuse replacement or you're brave enough, you can try rebending them slightly. **General warning**: There is a chance that the wire might break or become weaker (bending unintentionally) and if you have a gold or rose gold wire, it may change color (because the gold is only plated). The wire will never be perfectly straight again, but that doesn't matter much since it's hidden anyway. If you decide to rebend the wire, you do that at your own risk.

You need a pair of **small round nose pliers** for this (both tips of the pliers are round tubes and there is no edge on them). The tips must be small enough to fit into the bend. Any other type of pliers will probably leave ugly marks and won't let you bend the wire correctly.

Grab the wire right in the bend with the pliers, then **rotate the pliers** to unbend it slightly. Without letting go of the pliers, grab the very end of the wire and **push it upwards without rotating the pliers** to create a new bend very close behind where the old bend was.

You can see the pliers I mean and a little explanation of the technique [in this video (start at 0:19)](https://youtu.be/p0JrrI3PqLI?t=20)